# Is Aang also boosted by the comet?

Tags: avatar

If a Firebender gets boosted by the comet and Aang is also a Firebender, shouldn't his Firebender abilities also be stronger with the sun?

And of course the same with the moon and his waterbender abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sozin's_Comet) suggests Aang also effected.

> An Avatar-level firebender can produce fire whips, the most being five
>   at once. They are capable of reaching across long distances, displayed
>   when Aang used the technique hundreds of feet above Ozai. This may
>   have been a result of his firebending being augmented by Sozin's Comet
>   or because he was in the Avatar State at the time, or possibly a
>   combination of both. Each fire whip is also very wide and moves in a
>   similar fashion to squid or octopus tentacles. They have enough
>   destructive power to demolish large rock formations.

[image]